# IBInspectable not rendering Layer of NSView

Tags: macos, swift, interface-builder

I want to edit border width and background color of an `NSView` and made those values `IBInspectable`:

```
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat{
    set{
        layer?.borderWidth = newValue
    }
    get{
        return layer!.borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor{
    set{
        layer?.backgroundColor = newValue.CGColor
    }
    get{
        return NSColor(CGColor: layer!.backgroundColor)!
    }

}
```

In the `init` method, I wrote:

```
override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

    wantsLayer = true
    layer?.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

When I run the app, changes are shown correctly, but the view doesn't live-render in the interface builder. I don't get any errors or warnings either.

Comment: Did you also put @IBDesignable to the class definition.

Comment: yes I did: `@Designable class CDPProgressIndicator: NSView`

Answer (score 3):

i found the solution myself: it seems that the init Method does not get called when the view gets rendered in the Interface builder. As a solution i had to add a global variable which creates a `CALayer()` when needed:

```
@IBDesignable class CDPProgressIndicator: NSView {

// creates a CALayer() and sets it to the layer property of the view
var mainLayer: CALayer{
    get{
        if layer == nil{
            layer = CALayer()
        }
        return layer!
    }
}

//referencing to mainLayer ensures, that the CALayer is not nil 
@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat{
    set{
        mainLayer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
    get{
        return mainLayer.borderWidth
    }
}

@IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor{
    set{
        mainLayer.backgroundColor = newValue.CGColor
    }
    get{
        return NSColor(CGColor: mainLayer.backgroundColor)!
    }

}
```

and now it finally renders in the interface builder as well.

Comment: simply B R I L L I A N T. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The setting of `wantsLayer` is sufficient to have the layer created when running the app, but it doesn’t work in IB. You have to set the `layer` explicitly. I’d suggest doing this in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, that way you are using the approved technique, `wantsLayer`, in your app, but we handle the IB exception, too. For example:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: NSView {

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        didSet { layer!.borderWidth = borderWidth }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: NSColor {
        didSet { layer!.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor }
    }

    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor: NSColor {
        didSet { layer!.backgroundColor = backgroundColor.cgColor }
    }

    // needed because IB doesn't don't honor `wantsLayer`
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        layer = CALayer()
        configure()
    }

    override init(frame: NSRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        wantsLayer = true
        ...
    }
}
```

That handles this IB edge case (bug?), but doesn’t alter the standard flow when running the app.